# Equal partition of child divs into a parent div

Tags: html, css

I am having problems partitioning three child divs into a fixed size parent div. As seen in the photo, I want to partition these child divs with equal size inside the parent div. Please add a comment if you don't understand the question, but I'll post the photo down below so you will have a sense of what I am asking.

```css
.qm {
  height: 60%;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  box-shadow: 5px 7px 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 18%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
}

.qmheading {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.qmimage {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.qmparagraph {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="qm">
  <div class="qmheading">
    <h1>
      Quality Management
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="qmimage">
    <img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/beacon.svg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="qmparagraph">
    <p>
      ISO 9001 2015, <br> ISO 17025 & ISO 13485
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: By partitioning, do you mean that you want them to have equal heights?

Comment: Yes, I want all the three boxes to have equal sizes so the icon will be centered, since I am having problems centering the icon/vector of one box with the icon position of another box.

Comment: The image has divs of different heights - also you need a minwidth or your title will look bad

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add fixed heights, e.g., `height: 20vh;` to your child divs. I choose the height of 20vh because I assumed that the height of your parental div is 60% of the height of the view port. Therefore, 60vh/3 = 20vh.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried, first of all I added width and min-width to the parent div. Second, I added fixed height, padding and flex. Then, I added font-size and font-family to .gmparagraph as I removed p tag.

```css
    h1 {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    .qm {
        height: 60%;
        background: #fcfcfc;
        box-shadow: 5px 7px 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        border-radius: 20px;
        padding: 0 1rem;
        width: 310px;
        min-width: 18%;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .qm div{
        height: 120px; 
        padding: 5px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .qmheading {
       background-color: lightblue;
    }

    .qmimage {
       background-color: lightcoral;
    }

    .qmparagraph {
        background-color: lightgreen;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
<div class="qm">
  <div class="qmheading">
    <h1>
      Quality Management
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="qmimage">
    <img width=120 src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/beacon.svg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="qmparagraph">
      ISO 9001 2015, <br> ISO 17025 & ISO 13485
  </div>
</div>
```